# why the function does'nt return value as expected?

Tags: node.js

1.I have a function that establish db connection and returns the connection object or the db handle.It is passed as an argument to other functions that use CRUD functions.Code is written in Node js file.

```
    wrote two function one for db connection initiate and other to use the object returned by it


// function to return the db handle

    function getDbConnection()
    {
      var dc;
     MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        return db;   
      }); 
    }

// function to insert data

    function CreatePost(dbo)
    {

      console.log(typeof dbo);
      var mydbo = dbo.db("fb");
      for(var i=0;i<25;i++)
      {
        postData = { pstID: ""+i, pstTitle: "Highway 37",pstTime: "100",pstdBy: "100",pstCntnt: "100"};

        mydbo.collection("mypost").insertOne(postData, function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 document inserted"); 
        dbo.close(); 
      });
    }

    }


    var dbo = getDbConnection();
    CreatePost(dbo);



    Error shown while executing

     var mydbo = dbo.db("fb");
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of undefined
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: i changed the code    . Still it doesnt works                                                                                                                         CreatePost();

async function CreatePost()
{
  var dbo = await getDbConnection();
  await console.log("from second function"+typeof dbo);
  

}